# Regex modification - matching optionally dash (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to ask you how to modify that regex:

```
"/\b([A-Z]{2,}[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)/is"
```

as currently it can only match it if there would be not '-'. What I am trying to achieve is that in addition it can match something like that i.e.

```
TGW-1234
```

so at least 2 letters followed by (optionally) dash and then (required) digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `-?` between the letters and numbers. `?` means *optional*

```
"/\b([A-Z]{2,}-?[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)/is"
```

It is placed after the character that is allowed to appear at that point in the expression, but who's existence isn't actually required to still be considered a successful match.

Answer (score 1):

```
"/\b([A-Z]{2,}-?[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)/is"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"/\b([A-Z]{2,}-?[0-9][0-9A-Z-\/]*)/is"
--------------^^ optional dash
```